# Bing Map On GeoLocation Basis in iPhone Application

Tags: php, ios4, iphone, bing-maps

I need to display a bing map in an iphone app on basis of particular latitude and longitude.
So far i am able to display map on iphone by launching in uiwebview [This URL](http://springsvision.com/nextgeni/maptest.php)

I need here on where i would adjust this to load map on lat and long basis.

Any help/clue over this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I find that this url http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?o=xml&key=BingMapsKey returns some sort of xml but i'm unable to find where to use this to display the map?